# What is the equation of these coordinate points

Tags: graphing-functions

(2,2) 
(3,6) 
(4,24) 
(5,120) 
(6,720)
(7,5040)

I input all of these points into my calculator and ran every working equation none of which fits the equation. These equations include: Linear(obviously not), quadratic (also obviously not), cubic, quartic, natural log, exponential and power regressions none of which seem to fit. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Factorial function.  Or else you can drag in the Gamma function.

Comment: Should be $(2,2)$

Comment: I suspect that first point should be $(2,2)$; currently all pairs but the first are of the form $(n,n!)$.

Comment: There are 130 such sequences considering that the first term is $(2,2)$ but none if we let it be $(2,1)$, see [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=6%2C+24%2C+120%2C+720%2C+5040&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: There are infinitely many such sequences (though not necessarily interesting ones): Take the sequence to be points $(n, P(n))$ for $n = 2, \dots, 7$ for suitable polynomials $P$ of arbitrarily large degree.

Comment: You are all right, the point should definitely be (2,2)

Answer (score 1):

This is the Gamma Function, the continuous version of the factorial.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#The_Gamma_and_Pi_functions

Comment: Why is the Gamma function necessary here? The arguments are integers, and all but the first are of the form $(n,n!).$

Comment: @Semiclassical He is looking for a function to connect these points. You need the Gamma function because it is continuous.

Comment: Well, it depends on what the domain of the $x$-coordinate is. But I see your point, since the OP doesn't clarify that issue at all.

Comment: So basically there is no equation where only x and y are involved, wow that's pretty interesting. I'd never even heard of "n!" thanks for response.